# JQuery addclass not working on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have a website in which I use an AJAX pagination system. I then added a JQUERY call to add a class to some list items on my document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".products ul li:nth-child(3n+3)").addClass('last');
}
```

This all works correctly when the page is initially loaded, but when the AJAX pagination is used to change the page the addclass call is not made again. I think this is because the AJAX call does not fire the document ready function, so I think I need to add the addclass call to my AJAX POST call. I tried something like this, but can't get it to work.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/load_data.php",
    data: dataToSend,
    success: function(msg) {
        $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {   
            $(".products ul li:nth-child(3n+3)").addClass('last');

            loading_hide();
            $("#container").html(msg);
        });
    }
});
```

Am I correct in trying to add the addclass call in the AJAX succes callback? If so what needs to change? Or where does this call need to be placed?

Comment: Why are you binding an ajaxComplete handler in the success handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you load in your new data:

```
$("#container").html(msg);
```

Then apply the class:

```
$(".products ul li:nth-child(3n+3)").addClass('last');
```

All in the success method, so the final product:

```
success: function(msg) {
    $("#container").html(msg);
    $(".products ul li:nth-child(3n+3)").addClass('last');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works indeed, I was very close but this makes it work indeed! :) Thanks again.